# How to see, how much every computer in Wlan uses the connection?

Tags: networking

We have a 2MB wireless network in our home and 3 computers running internet through it. I'd like to see, how much my brothers computer uses the connection. Is there a program, which shows the connection-speed for all the computers inside network? I'm on Windows 7.

Thanks,
Martti Laine

Answer (score 1):

You'd most likely have to do it on the computer in question, or on the router - [ddwrt based routers can use rflow to do it](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Using_RFlow_Collector_and_MySQL_To_Gather_Traffic_Information).